# How to compare a value in csv to another csv with pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 2 CSV files which look something like these

```
SiteID  Price
A12     33
B98     48

SiteID  Price
B57     100
A12     33.5
```

what I am trying to do is from CSV1 look for A12 in CSV2 and if present compare the price with upto 10% difference. I tried doing this with pandas but not getting the right results. If not pandas then any other way of doing this in Python?
Here is my sample code

```
ab = df.loc[df['SiteID'] =='A12',['price']]
co = 33
if co>=ab-ab*0.1 and co<= ab+ab*0.1:
   print("Value is correct")
```

this leads to ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: This could be done by `merge`. What is your expected output?

Comment: If the value is within range just print and do nothing but if the value is out of range append the 'SiteID to a new list

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this with `merge` and boolean indexing:

```
# align the two dataframes by `SiteID`
s = df1.merge(df2, on='SiteID', how='left')

# valid rows where the ratio is between [0.9, 1.1]
valid_rows = (s['Price_x']/s['Price_y']).between(0.9,1.1)

# output
out = list(s.loc[valid_rows, 'SiteID'])
```

Output:

```
['A12']
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked but what if I want A12 only to be appended to list if its not in within the 10% range, example in CSV2 the value of A12 is 50 which is outside the 10% range of A12 in CSV1. I tried using NOT but that didnt work

Comment: Use `~valid_rows` instead of `valid_rows` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is simply because df.loc returns a dataframe and not a value so truth value cannot be determined.

Try:

```
ab = df.loc[df['SiteID'] =='A12']
for idx,rows in ab.iterrows():
    co = 33
    if co>=rows["Price"]-rows["Price"]*0.1 and co<= rows["Price"]+rows["Price"]*0.1:
       print("Value is correct")
```